# ¿ Como interrumpir un método que tarda demasiado en acabar y lanzar un mensaje?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Supongamos que tengo un programa en C# donde en un punto hay lo siguiente:

```
string dato;
dato = recogerDato();
SiguientePantalla("pantalla2.aspx");
```

Dentro del metodo recogerDato() puede haber una consulta a una base de datos, o un calculo que puede tardar bastante.
Dentro del metodo SiguientePantalla() hay un código donde el servidor nos lleva a otro formulario .aspx

¿ Hay alguna manera de controlar con algun timer u otra instrucción el tiempo que lleva ejecutandose el metodo recogerDato() o SiguientePantalla() y en caso digamos que tardara mas de 15segundos interrumpiera el proceso con una excepcion o algo parecido para mostrar un mensaje de "Tiempo de espera demasiado largo " para luego volver a ejecutarlo otra vez si quisieramos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede implementarse con el metodo **Join** de la clase **System.Threading.Thread**.

El fragmento de código sería como sigue, en donde:

- Se instancia un hilo para ejecutar el método que se demora considerablemente y que se desea abortar (en el ejemplo su metodo recogerDato)
- Se instancia un **TimeSpan** con el tiempo que se desea esperar como maximo por la ejecucion (15 segundos para este ejemplo)
- Se inicia la ejecución del metodo mediante el hilo en segundo plano
- Se invoca el metodo **Join** sobre el hilo, el cual bloquea el hilo principal por en el tiempo indicado (en el TimeSpan que se pasa por parametro). El metodo Join devuelve true si se termino de ejecutar en menos del tiempo indicado, false si toma mas tiempo
- Se aborta el hilo (th) que esta ejecutando el metodo recogerDato() en segundo plano. Tenga en cuenta que al invocar el metodo Abort se producirá una exepcion **ThreadAbortException** en el hilo que se esta abortando.

  ```
  var th = new Thread(recogerDato); //Se instancia un hilo par ejecutar
  var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15); //0 dias,horas,minutos 3 segundos
  th.Start();

  if (th.Join(ts)){
      //OK. th se terminó de ejecutar en menos de 3 segundos
  } else {
      //No
      th.Abort(); //Se aborta la ejecucion del hilo
      throw new System.Exception("Se supero el tiempo de espera para 
      ejecutar recogerDato");
  }
  ```

Para la ejecucion de su metodo **SiguientePantalla** que al parecer recibe un parametro string, sirve el mismo fragmento de codigo anterior con las siguientes modificaciones:

- Instanciar un delegado **ParameterizedThreadStart** para invocar el metodo **SiguientePantalla**

  ```
  System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart action;
  action = (obj) => {
      var prmInt = (string)obj;
      SiguientePantalla(prmInt);
  };
  ```
- Instanciar la clase **Thread** pero para ejecutar un metodo parametrizado

  ```
  th = new System.Threading.Thread(start: action);
  ```
- Al iniciar el hilo hay que pasarle los parametros deseados, en su caso la cadena **"pantalla2.aspx"**

  ```
  th.Start("pantalla2.aspx");
  ```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente ! Gracias